# How create array of Url Iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, arrays, sdk

Hi i wanna know how can i make this :

i have this...

```
networkImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"http:www.mydomain.com/photo.png", @"http:www.mydomain.com/photo2.png", @"http:www.mydomain.com/photo3.png", @"http:www.mydomain.com/photo4.png" ,nil];
```

and i wanna know if i can make this ..

```
NSArray * photo;    
networkImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: photo, nil];
```

i download the photo array fron web server parsing usin JSON.
i try this but i have a error of

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x383940'

sory for my english !

Comment: try this ->  [networkImages addObjectsFromArray:photo];

Comment: thanks i solved changing networkImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:photo];

Comment: @akk initWithObjects: should work as well. OP is missing something else.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want only one array in the array..
try this

```
NSArray * photo;    
networkImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray: photo];
```